# Creating a custom Debian LiveCD

Tags: linux, debian, livecd

How do I go about creating a custom Debian LiveCD with the following software applications installed and ready to use upon boot?

```
TrueCrypt
DropBox
Chromium
```

I have seen some online tools to do this, but I would prefer to do this without using the online livecd generators.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53471/linux-installation-to-livecd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya that can be done you have compile the package in iso file otherwise you can use cs50 iso image in which these application installed default.